# Como conectarme a una wifi con qt

Tags: c++, qt

Buenas tardes, alguien me puede ayudar? necesito realizar una aplicación en c++ mediante QT. La misma tiene que buscar las conexiones inalámbricas y conectarse a una especifica. Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: No creo que Qt tenga soporte nativo para eso. Supongo que tendrás que buscar una librería para hablar con el gestor de conexiones del sistema, o que tu aplicación deshabilite el gestor de conexiones para manejarlas tú directamente (tu aplicación debe hablar directamente con funciones nativas del sistema que te permitan escanear redes y demás). En cualquier caso, lo tendrías difícil, porque no creo que haya librerías multiplataforma para ninguna de las dos alternativas. Es decir, tu aplicación tendrá que detectar el sistema operativo y el gestor de conexiones, y utilizar una librería u otra.

Answer (score 5):

Si haces uso de la versión 5.6 (no sabría decir te si versiones anteriores disponen de ello), tienes a tu disposición la librería B2QtWifi que te permite acceder a características WIFI del equipo.

Así, por ejemplo, podrías listar las wifis disponibles en un `QListView` con un código tal que (sacado de la web de Qt):

```
auto m_wifiManager = QWifiManager::instance();
listView->setModel(m_wifiManager->networks());
```

Conectarte a la wifi seleccionada:

```
QModelIndex index = m_listView->currentIndex();
QWifiConfiguration config;
if (index.isValid()) {
    QString ssid = qvariant_cast<QString>(index.data(QWifiManager::SSID));
    config.setSsid(ssid);
    config.setPassphrase(/* clave para la wifi */);
    m_wifiManager->connect(&config);
}
```

Para más información, te recomiendo consultar la documentación en su fuente original:

- [Enlace al ejemplo](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtfordevicecreation-wifi-wifi-cpp-example.html)
- [Enlace a documentación de QWifiManager](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qwifimanager.html)

Un saludo.